# Qt GUI math application hangs out GUI while computing

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have a simple GUI for my application = I have to set some input parameters for my math function, then click 'compute' button, and function starts. Math function(s) are written in pure C so there are no objects, just functions.

It looks like this:

```
#include "mymath.h"

class myMath : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ...
    void compute();
};

void myMath::compute()
{
   //get parameters from gui
   call_C_fun();
   // save results to GUI
}
```

The main problem with this code is that when I click 'compute' (it does sooo much computation, it takes up to 5 minutes or so) it hangs out my GUI so I can't do anything else (I can't even see my GUI, window is "frozen" for the time that computation is running. After the function is finished, it prints out results on QLabels, and GUI is once again "alive". How can I solve this? I don't want my GUI to be "frozen" when computation takes time. Any ideas? I thought about `QThread` - but I'm kinda new in threads-thing, so please, give simple-easy-to-understand answers for newbie :)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/). Then do your computation in the thread object and send a signal once it's finished. Connect the signal to a slot in your class a do whatever you want to do with the result.

Comment: And there are two `:` semicolons after `class myMath` because... ?

Answer (score 6):

Factor out the computation to another thread, like this: -

```
// This is the object that will run the computation on a different thread
class Computation : public QObject
{
signals:
    void Finished();
public slots:
    void Compute();
};
```

Then create the other thread in your main window class and start it running: -

```
class MyMath : public QMainWindow
{
    public:
        void StartComputation();
};


MyMath::StartComputation()
{
    QThread* pThread = new QThread;
    Computation* pComputation = new Computation;

    // move computation to the new thread
    pCompuation->moveToThread(pThread);

    // Note Qt5 connection style    

    // ensure the computation starts when the thread starts
    connect(pThread, &QThread::started, pComputation, &Computation::Compute); 
    // when computation is finished, quit the thread
    connect(pComputation, &Compute::Finished, pThread, &QThread::quit);
    // have the thread tidy up when finished
    connect(pThread, &QThread::finished, pThread, &QThread::deleteLater);
    // start it!
    pThread->start();
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the `connect` syntax is new in Qt 5.

Comment: Which is why I commented it Qt 5.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rolling your own threading stuff, try the **built-in** [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qtconcurrent.html) namespace. It's easier, optimized and less error prone. There is no need to worry about moving stuff to other threads and performing explicit synchronization using mutexes.

[QtConcurrent::run](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) uses an internal thread pool to run your tasks and returns a [QFuture](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuture.html) with which you can interact using [QFutureWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfuturewatcher.html) and signals & slots. The names may sound complicated, but the code is very simple:

```
class MyMath : public QObject 
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit MyMath(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {
        this->watcher = new QFutureWatcher(this);
        connect(this->watcher, SIGNAL(finished()),
                this, SLOT(computationFinished()));
    }

public slots:

    void compute() {

        // This one is called by the user. Retrieve
        // the computation arguments (whatever they
        // may be), start the computation using 
        // QtConcurrent::run and prepare to receive
        // the results. 
        // 
        // Maybe update the UI to tell the user that 
        // the computationis being performed?

        Args args = getSomeArgs();
        QFuture<Result> res = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyMath::internalCompute, args);
        this->watcher->setFuture(res);
    }

    void computationFinished() {
        // The computation is done. Update the GUI
        // to display the results. Done.
    }

private:

    QFutureWatcher<Result>* watcher;

    Args getSomeArgs() const {
        // return arguments needed by compute.
    }

    Result internalCompute(Args args) const {
        // perform very expensive math.
    }
};
```

**Update.** After Merlin069's comment, I think it's not wise to recommend using the more complex operations provided by QtConcurrent.

Comment: Although if you're using QtConcurrent, then you should probably read this thread: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.devel/7942

Answer (score 2):

In your case, threading would be a solution. Your computation would be running in a separate thread which then would allow your GUI to be responsive while it computes whatever you need.

That's something quite common about GUI in my experience. GUI has its own thread(s), and your logic uses its own thread(s).

You can use then very simple patterns to handle this, with signal from the GUI that starts workers, and signals from the workers that triggers updates in the GUI.

You'll need to be careful about usual thread-safety concerns. I strongly suggest you learn a bit about threading in general to have a better grasp at what you're doing. It may also help you understand strange behaviors you may observe that may happen when using threaded code (which is not always trivial to people not used to it).

I also suggest you read [QThread documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qthread.html) which explains quite well how to implements threaded code in Qt (prefer the separate worker to the subclassing of Qthread, though). Take a look also at [QMutex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmutex.html) and [QMutexLocker](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmutexlocker.html) , you may need them.

Comment: For now on, did it subclassing `QThread` and using `QMutex` - works brilliant, cheers! Tomorrow I will try out other soulutions from this topic. And btw - why subclassing `QThread` is known as bad idea?

Comment: Re. subclassing `QThread`: read [this blog post](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Comment: @yak Andref linked a relevant article. It's not _always_ bad, but generally you should prefer the worker approach. Then, this link is also relevant, about [Why it's not always bad to subclass QThread](http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html). Really short answer: if you don't need an event loop, subclass, if you need an event loop (signals, slots, etc), then don't subclass.

Answer (score 2):

**Qt GUI math application hangs out GUI while computing**

*I have a simple GUI for my application ...*..

*The main problem with this code is that when I click 'compute' (it does sooo much computation, it takes up to 5 minutes or so) it hangs out my GUI so I can't do anything else (I can't even see my GUI, window is "frozen" for the time that computation is running. After the function is finished, it prints out results on QLabels, and GUI is once again "alive". How can I solve this? I don't want my GUI to be "frozen" when computation takes time. Any ideas? I thought about QThread - but I'm kinda new in threads-thing, so please, give simple-easy-to-understand answers for newbie :)*

It seems that your Program(GUI) never hang. It goes on processing with the  'call_C_fun()' of 'compute()' function. But the GUI is not Responsive. See the reference of **Keeping the GUI Responsive** at http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq27-responsive-guis.html . 
The recurring problem of GUIs' freezing during long operations can be deal with many method. But the simplest way is **Manual event processing**.

To be with **Manual event processing**, one have to call *QCoreApplication::processEvents()* periodically inside your loop.

The following example shows how to work:

```
call_C_fun(){
....
while(Your_loop_condition) {
    ....
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    if (!your_compute_button->isChecked()) {
        //"Aborted"
        return;
    }
}
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a full `QThread` solution, you could also use `QEventLoop` to create a separate event loop to run your computation in to keep the main event loop (which hosts the UI) free. It's not as flexible as `QThread` but they're incredibly quick to implement.

Comment: They also expose a whole big bag of problems, since suddenly the entirety of your GUI code has become reentrant.

Comment: I thought that the GUI code would only become reentrant if you were mixing the computation classes into the GUI, and not separating them and calling out through the signal/slots system? I could be wrong, it's been a long while since I looked into it.

Comment: Wherever you see `exec()` in your own code is a place where any of the `QObject::event()` methods can be re-entered. That's all it takes. Of course, technically if you merely create an event loop for fun and then destroy it without running it via `exec()`, you're OK, but surely that's not what you meant :)

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that, guess you learn something new everyday.